# doing a GET request to bitbucket-api using curl

Tags: php, bitbucket-api

I'm trying to do a simple GET request and return whatever the response is too the screen. When i load the page i get a blank page. I feel like im close, but im not sure where i am going wrong.

I'm assuming that i should get some kind of response if it worked succesfully.

```
    $url='https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/user/';

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not return a blank page, you need to write

```
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

or
delete this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Also you need add 
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`
before curl_exec

Comment: This works great, i just needed to add the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', false);` line